# How do I match input password (api) to django admin password?

Tags: python, django, api, passwords

I am not doing authentication here I am just getting the user for sending OTP.
I am taking email and password to validate but my password not converting to the algorithm if I enter 'a' then it will match it with Django stored hashers password.

```
email = self.serializer.validated_data['email']
password = request.data['password']
user = User.objects.get(email=email, password=password)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since django hashes the password, I would suggest to just use [**`check_password`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password) to let it do the same hashing on the incoming password in the data:

```
email = self.serializer.validated_data['email']
password = request.data['password']
user = User.objects.get(email=email)
is_credentials_valid = user.check_password(password)
```